# WCF : Not getting operations(Methods present on service) at client side

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service with 4 operations in it.
I have hosted it on IIS succesfully, added its service reference succesfully to client side. After Creating the object of the service class I am not getting the opreations(methods) present on the service.
Did you ever faced such issue? please help.. **Below Image shows the operations at service side**
 [image]

**Below Image respresent that the operations are not reflecting here.**
[image]

**Here is the snapshot of the WSDL.**
[image]

**Snapshot of Definition of the IRequiredForms201410PortType interface**
[image]

Comment: Can you post the definition of the IRequiredForms201410PortType interface?

Comment: please Check it I have added the screenshot. @milanio

Comment: https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/introToAngular

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service reference was not added correctly. You should try unchecking options like "reuse types in referenced assemblies" in the service reference configuration.

Also, the full webservice code would help.

Comment: I have looked in WSDL and there is no operation element present. So if there in no operation element in wsdl, we will not get the methods here at client side... right?

Comment: Tried doing what you have suggested... not worked :(

Comment: 1. You did not list the full wsdl - there is another one included: ?wsdl=wsdl0

Comment: 2. Please post the full code for using the proxy class (prdClient = ...).

Comment: Code for creation of proxy class is here :`ServiceReference1.requiredForms201410PortTypeClient prdClient = new ServiceReference1.requiredForms201410PortTypeClient();`

Comment: Could you post the definition of the requiredForms201410PortTypeClient class please?

Comment: Very first image in the questions define the requiredForms201410PortTypeClient class.

Comment: In that image you show requiredForms201410PortType, not requiredForms201410PortTypeClient.

Comment: okay @TAMTAM .. So on client side.. I have added the service reference named `ServiceReference1`. Created an object of `requiredForms201410PortTypeClient `  as `ServiceReference1.requiredForms201410PortTypeClient prdClient = new ServiceReference1.requiredForms201410PortTypeClient();` Now from that object I am trying to locate the operation but I am not getting those operations here. :(

Comment: Well let's see the code for requiredForms201410PortTypeClient then.

Comment: Press F12 -> go to class definition -> copy&paste the code.